# How to ask IntelliJ to use wrapped maven (mvnw or mvnw.cmd)?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wrapper

I just added wrapped Maven (https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) to my Maven project, and I'm wondering if there's a way to configure IntelliJ IDEA (at project level) to use wrapped Maven (`./mvnw`) instead of looking at Maven Home.

Comment: Not yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146205.

Comment: There's an all new non-official plugin, but I don't know if it works for now : https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10160-maven-wrapper-intellij-idea-plugin

Comment: Looking into this in 2020, and I am hearing noise about intellij supporting it, but haven't seen how to do it. Bump to this issue

Answer (score 7):

There's no [official support for Maven Wrapper](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146205) yet, but the third-party plugin "Maven Wrapper support" by Stephan Pauxberger works for me:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10633-maven-wrapper-support

I use it with IDEA 2018.3.